# UISegmentedControl on a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UITableViewController` hosted in a `NavigationController` which is in a Tab.

I wish to have a `UISegmentedControl` float over the table so that as the table scrolls, the UISegmentedControl is visible.

To what subview do I add the `UISegmentedControl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your `UISegmentedController` to your `UINavigationController` as a `UIBarButtonItem` with something along the lines of:

```
UISegmentedController * sc = ...
sc.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                      initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];

myUINavigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
```

-- if you want to have the `UISegmentedController` float on top of your table (obscuring it) you should add a transparent UIView that sits above the `UITableView` and stick it in there. But that's probably not what you want.